# Having issue with with Progress Dialog using Acr.UserDialogs in xamarin forms iOS App

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am having a problem with showing progress bar using nuget package (Acr.UserDialog) in xamarin forms iOS. with the same code snippet, its working well in Android platform.

```
using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Loading", null, null, true, MaskType.Black)) {
    await Task.Run(() => {
        // Code Logic Goes here ...
    });
}
```

A version of ACR UserDialogs Library:

PCL Project - v6.5.1

iOS Project - v7.0.0

if anyone knows the solution for this issue, please provide a solution.

Comment: in iOS, what issue do you have exactly?

Comment: I saw you report the issue [here](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/issues/525) , and the author has replied you.

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67832/implementing-file-picker-example-into-a-cross-platform-application

Please check this:

```
var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();

if (file != null)
{
    var fileFullName = file.FilePath.Substring(file.FilePath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).Substring(1);
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("Pick_" + extension + "_File_" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MMddyyyy_hhmmss"));


    using (Stream stream = file.GetStream())
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(ms);
        filePath = ms.ToArray().SaveAttachmentInLocalFolder(fileName, extension);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task GetPdfDataAsync(byte[] fileBytes)
{
    try
    {
        var localPath = string.Empty;
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        localPath =
            Task.Run(() => _localFileProvider.SaveFileToDisk(fileBytes, $"{fileName}.pdf")).Result;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(localPath))
        {
            await PageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Error loading PDF", "Computer says no", "OK");
            return;
        }

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            Pdfviewsource = $"file:///android_asset/pdfjs/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={WebUtility.UrlEncode(localPath)}";
        else
        {
            Pdfviewsource = localPath;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception) {  }
}
```

Comment: https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/showing-pdf-files-xamarin-forms/